# How to return exception from WCF server to client while creating client object

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, constructor

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1()
    {
        //check for a condition 
        // if condition fails throw exception to client
    }
}
```

I want the constructor itself to inform the client that client object can not be created. The condition checking whether a value is set or not in `Web.config`.

Comment: What sort of protocol are you using? HTTP?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? WCF already provides FaultExceptions to send failure messages to the client. The constructor is not (and should not) be a part of a web service *action*, it's part of the service implementation. Failed constructor = failed service = no method calls. WCF already takes care of the only meaningful scenario - map the exception to a ServiceFault that can be processed by the client. Create and throw your own FaultException if you need, but don't try to re-invent what's already there